# Rubocop - Disabling error flags (not cops)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have:

```
STEAK_HASH = {
                 'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Rare)': 1,
                 'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Medium Rare)': 2,
                 'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Medium)': 3,
                 'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Medium Well)': 4,
                 'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Well Done)': 5
               }
```

Which is valid ruby. When I run rubocop I get:

```
app/models/venue_category.rb:12:52: E: unexpected token tCOLON
(Using Ruby 2.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
             'Chargrilled Sirloin Steak (Rare)': 1,
```

This is obviously targeting ruby 2.1. In my rubocop.yml file I have:

```
TargetRubyVersion: 2.3.1
```

So my two options.. either get it targeting my version of ruby or just disable the error warning?

Comment: `TargetRubyVersion: 2.3.1` isn't a valid setting because Rubocop only accepts minor versions. Did you try `TargetRubyVersion: 2.3` instead?

Comment: I just love steak hash. It beats corned beef hash any day.

Comment: Doesn't the file name need to be `.rubocop.yml`? See: http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/